# Get Eclipse to select a maven profile when deploying to tomcat

Tags: eclipse, maven, profile

Can anyone tell me how I can get a profile to be picked up when running a web project from inside eclipse. This is my latest attempt, which does not work (file-dev.xml not parsed). I have a war project which has a dependency on a jar project. Th jar project contains the spring beans.

in pom.xml of jar project:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <env>dev</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>uat</id>
        <properties>
            <env>uat</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Also in the pom, I have added this to the maven-jar-plugin

```
<configuration>
  <argLine>-Dspring.profiles.active=dev</argLine>                   
</configuration>
```

in spring config xml file:

```
<import resource="file.xml" />
```

in file.xml

```
<import resource="file-dev.xml" />
```

in file-dev.xml

```
<beans profile="dev">
 <bean id="myBean"> etc etc </myBean>
</beans>
```

running mvn help:active-profiles returns " - dev"

Any idea what I cma missing? I have not tried any maven build or install yet, I just want it working in the dev environment, so we can deploy to tomcat from within eclipse first.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think argLine is a valid parameter for the maven jar plugin. And if it were, it would only set that property while it is creating the jar, not during runtime of the war. The maven configuration cannot govern runtime system parameters for the war, unless you use something like cargo or the tomcat plugin to have maven deploy the war directly (not via eclipse).Only option may be to explicitly set -Dspring.profiles.active=dev in the VM options of your tomcat config in eclipse.

Comment: how are you deploying to tomcat, directly via eclipse or using the tomcat plugin? If you are just trying to activate a profile when building in eclipse with m2e, then you can set the profile to be activated based on property `m2e.version`. This property will be set by m2e when an m2e build is done.